# Answering question that is On Hold?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope, close-reasons

My question, [What is my coordinate system preserving?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/193817/what-is-my-coordinate-system-preserving) was put on hold as being to broad. I made some edits to the question to try and make it more focused, and after doing some further research and checking out some recommended links, I feel I could answer my question (within a paragraph or two like the 'too broad' reason suggests).

Should I add my answer as a comment and hope it doesn't get closed based on my ability to add a clear and concise solution? Or should I wait and see if my edits made the question more clearly specific to others?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I added my re-open vote to the others that were already on your question so it is now ready for you to self-answer.

I agreed with its original closure as too broad, but I am almost always happy to re-open a question when someone says that they have an answer ready.